# SQL STATEMENT QUERY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table1Name with data populated and table2 with no data populated.

```
select * from [database1Name].dbo.table1Name 
join [database1Name].dbo.table2Name 
on [database1Name].dbo.table1Name.fieldName like value;
```

After running the above sql statement it joins the tables but does not show any populated data from the table 'table1Name'.

Why does this happen?

Comment: give us an example please

Answer (score 5):

Using `JOIN` which is an `INNER JOIN` means that it will get you only data where the condition matches. So if the second table has not data, then the condition is never met, so you get no data in return.

In your case you need a `LEFT JOIN`. This will get all the rows from the left table (table1Name in your case) and the corresponding values from the right table when the condition is met.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   [database1Name].dbo.table1Name 
       LEFT JOIN [database1Name].dbo.table2Name 
           ON [database1Name].dbo.table1Name.fieldName like [database1Name].dbo.table2Name.fieldName;
```

Just to mention that using joins mean that you might get multiple times a single row from a specific table. For instance since you have a `LIKE` condition, if `fieldName` of Table 1 matches fieldName in 2 rows from Table 2 then you will get two rows containing the same row from Table 1 and the two rows from Table 2:

Example:

**Table1**

```
FieldName 
1
2
```

**Table2**

```
FieldName OtherField
1         1
1         2
```

**Result of LEFT JOIN**

```
T1FieldName T2FieldName T2OtherField
1           1           1
1           1           2
2           NULL        NULL
```

Comment: Hi Giannis, I get the logic now, thanks! Your comment was very helpful.

Comment: On that note what does the percentage (%) wild character do?

Comment: `LIKE` is an operator that checks if two string type fields look alike. `LIKE` needs wildcards. If you do not use wildcards then it is effectively an equality operator. % means `any character sequence` than means that % matches any length of any characters.